# Detecting views on android viewpager

Tags: android, if-statement, android-viewpager

i got a simple question that i'll explain with my code:

```
public class myAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.id.layout1;
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.id.layou2;
                break;
        }
        return collection.findViewById(resId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }
}
```

on my activity:

```
myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter();
ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Is there any way i can detect wich of the 2 layouts (more in future) is currently displayed?

For example:

If (layout1 is currently displayed / inflated) { do something }, etc..

Thanks!

P.s i'm not using fragments has explained by the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
int currentPage = myPager.getCurrentItem();
switch(currentPage){
    case 0:
        // code for your first page
        break;
    case 1:
        // code for your second page
        break;
}
```